Why does the 64bit Linux Mint Live run on my 32bit machine?
Just made my Live-USB from 64bit Mint 21.3 (https://www.linuxmint.com/torrents/linuxmint-21.3-xfce-64bit.iso.torrent) and plugged into my old 32bit laptop, forgetting it still is such old. (Probably it's not relevant, but in any case: I created the USB stick basically following the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1227225/602021)
Everything boots and runs fine, new software comes from amd64 repository, is installable and runs also.
How can that be, given that it is software for another architecture?
EDIT:
Laptop chipset & model:
$ lscpu 
Architecture:           i686
  CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:        36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 2
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0,1
Vendor ID:              GenuineIntel
  Model name:           Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T6600  @ 2.20GHz
    CPU family:         6
    Model:              23
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 2
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           10
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 66%
    CPU max MHz:        2200,0000
    CPU min MHz:        1200,0000
    BogoMIPS:           4388,93
    Flags:              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse 
                        sse2 ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est
 
$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information' 
System Information
    Manufacturer: Acer           
    Product Name: Extensa 5220                   
    Version: 0100           


The simple answer is below. You're probably misunderstanding a laptop that had a 32bit OS preinstalled with the hardware being 32bit. It clearly isn't.

If amd64 packages work on your laptop, without QEMU, then it’s a 64-bit x86 system. The T6600 CPU is a 64-bit x86 CPU.
Note that 64-bit PCs have been the norm for over 15 years (arguably since 2006).
(I’m not even sure QEMU can emulate 64-bit x86 on 32-bit x86, so that might not be relevant.)

Uh, OK, if I lookup the processor now, it seems like – shame on me. Bought it some years ago (used via *bay), as replacement for the original single core one, and always thought it would also be 32bit, because of "Architecture: i686" (and would have sworn it was 32bit, and I aready tried x64 at least one time before).
But where does then this lscpu outcome with "Architecture: i686" result from?

“Architecture: i686” indicates that the kernel is running in 32-bit mode, or that lscpu is running with a 32-bit personality. If the former, 64-bit packages shouldn’t work; a 64-bit kernel can run 32- and 64-bit programs, but a 32-bit kernel can only run 32-bit programs.

TYVM for clarifying
